# using ifeq statement in makefile, missing separator even when indented with tab correctly

Tags: makefile

I was just practising with GNU make and I was trying to write a `clean` target, the make file is this:

```
includePath := -I $(CURDIR)
outputDir = $(CURDIR)/output
COMPILER := g++
standard := -std=c++17

#sourceFiles
main.cpp := main.cpp

#output files
binaryPath = $(outputDir)
binary = main.out
#int_binaryPath = intermediate binary
int_binaryPath = $(outputDir)/int_binaries
int_binary = main.o


GPP = $(COMPILER) $(standard) $(includePath)

#print info while make is executing
# $(info $(includeDir) ) 


VPATH = outputDir/int_binaries $(CURDIR)/glad/src


#build=compile,link and run

$(binary): $(int_binary) glad.c -lGL -lGLU -lglfw -ldl
    $(GPP) $(int_binaryPath)/main.o $(CURDIR)/glad/src/glad.c -o $(binaryPath)/$@  -lGL -lGLU -lglfw -ldl

$(int_binary): $(main.cpp)
    $(GPP) $(main.cpp) -c -o $(int_binaryPath)/$(int_binary)  

build: $(binary)
    $(binaryPath)/$(binary)

build@bg: $(binary)
    $(binaryPath)/$(binary) &

rebuild: clean build
    @echo "rebuild successful"


.PHONY: clean 
clean:
    ifeq($(wildcard $(outputDir)/$(binary)), $(outputDir)/$(binary))
        rm -rf $(outputDir)/$(binary)
    else ifeq($(wildcard $(outputDir)/$(int_binary)), $(outputDir)/$(int_binary))
        rm -rf $(outputDir)/$(int_binary)
    endif
```

**now the part that is throwing up error is this:**

```
.PHONY: clean 
clean:
    ifeq($(wildcard $(outputDir)/$(binary)), $(outputDir)/$(binary)) #this has spaces, line 47
        rm -rf $(outputDir)/$(binary) #this has 2 tabs, but even 1 tab didn't work
    else ifeq($(wildcard $(outputDir)/$(int_binary)), $(outputDir)/$(int_binary))
        rm -rf $(outputDir)/$(int_binary)
    endif
```

now, when I do `make clean`, it returns the following error:

```
makefile:47: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? Why isn't it working and what does the error mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have a space between the `ifeq` and the open paren.

You have other issues; for example there's no comma between words in the `wildcard` function, so you're literally asking it to look for the file `./output/main.out,` (including the `,`) exists.

Anyway, this is not needed because `rm -rf foo` is simply a no-op if `foo` doesn't exist... you don't need all this complexity.

Comment: but, I closed the wildcard function before the comma, shouldn't that end the function?]

Comment: I do need it since I have a `rebuild` target, which gets rid of old files and builds it again, if there is no file the buld stops

Comment: there are two more errors after I make the above amends: `makefile:49: extraneous text after 'else' directive
makefile:52: *** missing 'endif'.  Stop.` can you tell me if I've written the else ifdef correctly and whether I need a second endif

Comment: Most likely your version of GNU make is too old.  This syntax was introduced in GNU make 3.81 (released in 2006).  What does `make --version` say?

Comment: (of course, you have to have a space after the `ifeq` in the `else` as well)

Comment: it says version 4.2.1

Comment: Make sure you have `else ifeq (...)` (space after `ifeq`) and that none of your preprocessor operations (`ifeq`, `else`, `endif`) are indented with TAB.  It worked for me.

Comment: You don't need these, though.  I don't know what you mean by "if there is no file the build stops"; it must be something different than this clean rule.  If you use the `-f` option to `rm` then `rm` will not fail even if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: (you're right about the comma not being a problem... I miscounted the parens sorry about that!)